# iOS7 UIPickerView / UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uipickerview

I'm using a UIPickerView in a somewhat unorthodox way to allow users to select a series of images (in this case, they're words on a background, but they can just easily be pictures):

[image]

Under iOS6 this worked great, but with iOS7 as you can see, the edges of the images fade to white, which makes the control unusuable for this purpose.

My question are --

a) Would there be a way of "fixing" this and still using the UIPickerView control?  If so, what kind of approach might one take?

b) If I can't modify the views to eliminate the problem, would a practical alternative to be to use three UIScrollViews to replicate this functionality?

c) I have at times modified the views presented in a UIPickerView, and I'm considering trying to do that here, i.e., to just plug in my own replacement views.  But I'm unclear on whether that is practical... I'm questioning how the blur effect is added to these views at the top and bottom and how I might go about eliminating them.

That's a lot for one post; I'm just trying to decide what the best approach might be to deal with this issue.

TIA for any suggestions or guidance...

Comment: No, no answer yet -- I've put this problem off while I deal with a couple of other things.  Current game plan is to try replacing the views with views of my own (which I have done previously with pickerviews and it seems like that might work); if that doesn't work I'm going to build something out of UIScrollViews...

Answer (score 0):

I ended up making some adjustments to the implementation that improved the appearance somewhat.  We slightly increased the overall size of the picker by scaling it 1.25 (when in portrait view) or 1.40 (when in landscape view).  At the same time, I slightly reduced the size of the images in the picker.  The end result was that overall the frame was bigger, but the images were about the same size as before.  But the regions where the appearance is blurred are safely out of view unless one really looks hard for them.  We have judged this will work for now.

Ultimately, the UIPickerView has, in our opinion, taken a huge step backward with ios7.  We are anticipating the need to write something of our own to accommodate our needs in the long run but these changes have allowed us to get by for now.